# Situation where FFD < BFD

Tags: algorithms

I am practicing for an exam and one of the exercises is:

> Find an example sequence where FFD (offline) performs better than BFD (offline).

Intuitively I would say no such sequence exists as the sequence is sorted, but I have not managed to find a counterexample or proof.

Comment: FFD? BFD? More context would probably be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't *First/Best Fit Decreasing* always considered *offline* (requiring sorting the input assumed unsorted)?
Anyway, let me assume "performs better" to mean *uses less bins*.
I find it annoyingly hard to try to find an example using a minimum number of items, of item values and minimum item values - and to argue convincingly that it *is* minimal, but

> try a bin size of 16 and items of 11, 6, 6, 3, 2, 2, 2. Bin contents after adding each item:
>  - FF: 11 11,6 11,12 14,12 16,12 16,14 16,16
>  - BF: 11 11,6 11,12 11,15 13,15 15,15 15,15,2